# Как настроить таблицы DataBase и JavaCode таким образом что бы данные сначала добавлялись в главную таблицу а потом благодаря FOREIGN KEY в дочернюю

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rest, many-to-many

Я пишу REST API приложение на SpringBoot. Использую MySQL. У меня есть сущности User и Role, связанные друг с другом @ManyToMany. У меня есть таблица authorities которую я использую в качестве @JoinTable. Таблица authorities имеет два столбца: username - который является вторичным ключом для связи с таблицей users, и authority который делает то же для таблицы roles.
При добавлении нового user в таблицу user я получаю:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Поискав в интернете я обнаружил, что такая ошибка возникает если я пытаюсь добавить в дочернюю таблицу значение которого нет в главной таблице. С таблицей roles такой проблемы нет, потому что там всего два значения которыми я оперирую: "USER" и "ADMIN".
После внимательного изучения контроллера и метода createUser() которым я пользуюсь, я уверен что запись должна создаваться сначала в таблице user, а потом благодаря cascade добавляться в таблицу authority.
Очевидно я что-то упускаю из вида. Прошу помочь.
Здесь SQL код для создания таблиц:

```
  CREATE TABLE users (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(30) NOT NULL unique,
  password varchar(30),
  enabled tinyint(1),
  vote_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (vote_id) REFERENCES vote_db.votes(id));
  
  CREATE TABLE roles (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  role varchar(30) NOT NULL unique,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));
  
  CREATE TABLE authorities (
  username varchar(30),
  authority varchar(25),
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username) on update cascade on delete cascade,
  FOREIGN KEY (authority) REFERENCES roles(role) on update cascade on delete cascade);
```

Мой класс User

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "authorities"
            , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username")
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vote_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Vote vote;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String password, Role... roles) {
        this.username = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(roles));
    }
```

Getters и Setters я опускаю что бы не захламлять, там ничего имеющего отношение к вопросу нет.

Мой класс Role:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "roles")
    public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`введите сюда код`
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "authorities"
            , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority")
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"))
    private Set<User> users;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
```

Мой Controller (только метод createUser() так как остальные методы работают с другими сущностями и с ними нет проблем):

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/admin/users")
    public class AdminUserRestController {

    private final UserService userService;

    private final RoleService roleService;

    public AdminUserRestController(UserService userService, RoleService roleService) 
    {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.roleService = roleService;
    }

    @PostMapping`
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }
```

UserService и RoleService стандартны, просто возвращают данные полученные из репозитория (extends JpaRepository, без своей логики)

Comment: благодаря cascade, данные могут добавляться и удаляться, но никак не добавляться.  зы: связи в таблицах создают обычно на первичные ключи, а не на уникальные столбцы имен

Comment: "добавляться и удаляться, но никак не добавляться"?